# Help me to understand it

Tags: solidity, uniswap, decentralized-exchange, uniswapv3

```
if (
            _zeroForOne
                ? _sqrtPriceLimitX96 > _slot0.sqrtPriceX96 ||
                    _sqrtPriceLimitX96 < TickMath.MIN_SQRT_RATIO
                : _sqrtPriceLimitX96 < _slot0.sqrtPriceX96 &&
                    _sqrtPriceLimitX96 > TickMath.MAX_SQRT_RATIO
        ) {
            revert InvalidPriceLimit();
        }
```

In this code - it is saying that if `_zeroForOne` is true then keep it beetween `_slot0.sqrtPriceX96` and `TickMath.MIN_SQRT_RATIO` and if false then keep it between `_slot0.sqrtPriceX96` and `TickMath.MAX_SQRT_RATIO`, but what the `if` condition  is saying over it?

Answer (score 0):

It is checking  if the given `_sqrtPriceLimitX96` value is valid for the given swap transaction based on the `_zeroForOne` value.

And if the value is not within the range, the function will revert with an error.